# manipulate querySelectorAll elements without looping over the NodeList

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodelist

With jQuery it's possible to use the `addClass` / `removeClass` / `toggleClass` methods to manipulate classes.

We can do similar things the new native Node methods - using classList - but one problematic situation is when we need to make manipulations to a set of elements.

How would a method which abstracts the looping look like so we don't need to convert the NodeList returned by querySelectorAll into an Array and `forEach` it every time manually?

e.g. :

```
const tableRows = [...document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr')];
tableRows.forEach((element) => {
  // do stuff for every element here
});
```

My solution to that was

```
Array.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
  this.forEach((element) => {
    element.classList.add(className);
  });
};

Array.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
  this.forEach((element) => {
    element.classList.remove(className);
  });
};
```

but adding methods on the prototype isn't a good idea.

Comment: Nope. You need to loop. This is the same as jQuery and Node are doing, it's just that you don't see it

Comment: changed my question. naturally I know jQuery does this under the hood, would just like to recreate it (this time with the native classList)

Answer (score 1):

Even with jQuery - under the hood, it does exactly the same.
A jQuery object has a list of all the DOM elements, and when you call a method on the jQuery's object - it loops over all the DOM elements and call that specific method on the DOM element.

Check this for example:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/classes.js#L29

Eventually - it's the same.

Note that jQuery does more things, so if you are looking at efficiency - probably a code that you will write will be a bit more efficient (in case you are talking about looping a list of elements in order to add/remove classes).

Comment: yes, in fact this is my question, how would this efficient code look like - I understand what jQuery does under the hood (so I edited my question)

Comment: If you create a code that does *only* that - it will be (a bit) more efficient that jquery.

Comment: Did you try something out?

Comment: I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239963/adding-native-array-prototype-methods/44240373#44240373

Comment: The question is described on the aforementioned link Dekel .