# Adding Native Array prototype methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'd like to add two methods in the `Array.prototype` which will work a bit like addClass / removeClass of jQuery. This is what I've written:

```
Array.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
  this.forEach((element) => {
    element.classList.add(className);
  });
};

Array.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
  this.forEach((element) => {
    element.classList.remove(className);
  });
};
```

I was told it's generally a bad idea to add methods to built in JS prototypes, so I was wondering what the best alternatives would be to avoid potential gotchas.

My ideas :

1. check if the method already exists
2. just make a normal function that takes 2 arguments, the array and the classname
3. create my new custom object which will have the DOM manipulation methods I build

I am also looking at https://github.com/franciscop/umbrella/blob/master/src/plugins/addclass/addclass.js and how it's implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, sometimes we love to have some extra methods in the built in JS prototypes. In these situations I check if it already exists and if not you should use `Object.defineProperty` so that the method is not enumerable:

```
if (!Array.prototype.addClass)
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'addClass', {
    value: function(className) {
        this.forEach((element) => {
            element.classList.add(className);
        });
    }
})
```

You may check all the options you have in [mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).